# limits and continuity proof multivariate calculus

Tags: limits

Hi could any help me to prove this statement.

If k is an integer, 1 < k < m and consider the function $f:R^m \rightarrow R $, given by $f(x_1,x_2,...x_m)=x_k $
Show that f is continuous.

I believe that i must use the definition of the limit 0<[[x-a]]< E when [[f(x)-L]]< E to prove it but i dont know how to use it. Could anyone help me. I believe this involves some use of vectors as well such as finding the magnitude of vectors.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a problem in your question. You say that $f$: $R^m\to R^1$ so $f$ is a scaler function. But you define $f$ to be $f(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_m)=xk$. So in my understanding that by $x$ you mean $x=(x_1,x_2,\ldots, x_m)$ is a vector and hence $f$ is from $R^m$ to $R^m$. In this case, fix any $x_0\in R^m$ and you see that for any $\epsilon>0$ you just ask $\|x-x_0\|<\epsilon/k$ you will have $\|f(x)-f(x_0)\|\leq \epsilon$ and you are done.

Comment: He meant $x_k$, the $k$th element of the vector $x$

Answer (score 0):

$\textbf{Hint:}$
To show that $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to y}f(x)=f(y)$, you can start with $\epsilon>0$ and

use the fact that if $||x-y||<\delta$, then $|f(x)-f(y)|^2=|x_k-y_k|^2\le|x_1-y_1|^2+\cdots+|x_n-y_n|^2<\delta^2$.